# Rails OmniAuth Facebook 'Redirect URL must be absolute'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, facebook-oauth, callbackurl

I am trying to set up omniauth to allow users to sign in to my website with facebook. I get the following error when i click on the log in button after following the [Github Tutorial](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview)

[image]

In my devise.rb file i have:

```
  config.omniauth :facebook, "*****", "*****",
            callback_url: "CALLBACK_URL"
```

I am using ngrok so i am able to test with a url that isnt localhost. The url generated is http://46cbf60d.ngrok.io

In the facebook dashboard settings i have:
[image]
[image]

And in the facebook dashboard 'products/facebook login' i have
[image]

Does anybody know how to fix this error?

Comment: give the https:// version of the url from the same ngrok server. And also u need to up the ngrok .. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `devise.rb` file, 'CALLBACK_URL' needs to be replaced with the callback url such as http://demo-app.herokuapp.com/users/auth/facebook/callback

Comment: it's also worth pointing out that you will see the same error if you pass a path, instead of a full url